# Predictions from a weibull fit don't match original data distribtuion

Tags: r, weibull

As a follow on from this question: [Interpreting Weibull parameters from survreg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9113872/interpreting-weibull-parameters-from-survreg), I'm trying to understand why histograms from predictions based on the model fit don't seem to match histograms of the original data. Example using code borrowed from that question:

```
library(survival)
y <- rweibull(1000, shape=2, scale=5)
r <- survreg(Surv(y)~1, dist="weibull")
a <- 1/r$scale      # Approximately 2
b <- exp( coef(r) ) # Approximately 5
y2 <- b * ( -log( 1-runif(1000) ) ) ^(1/a)
y3 <- rweibull(1000, shape=a, scale=5)

df2 <- data.frame(y,y2,y3)
df2 <- gather(df2)

ggplot(df2, aes(x = value, fill=key)) + geom_histogram()
```

The plot looks like this:

[image]

Why is the height reached on the y axis different for each y?

Comment: The bars are stacked. Try plotting them in different facets or do `geom_histogram(position = "dodge")`.

Comment: omg your are right and not the first time i've been cuahgt by this ‍♂️. apologies all - embarrassed now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `geom_histogram(position = "identity")`.